# Determine if a table exists when performing an EF Migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I recently switched from .edmx to Code First and am trying to implement migrations.  Is it possible to determine if a table exists before calling `CreateTable` in a DbMigration's `Up()` function?  I have an initial migration set to create the tables, but existing databases should not apply this initial migration.

I am using EF 6.1 and .Net 4.6

Comment: You can always call `Sql(...)` with bare ddl sql that checks the existence and then adds the table if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, but it would require me using raw sql to create the table instead of the fluent api.

Comment: Well, I guess you could add an entry manually into the _MigrationHistory table, but that might just be a work around

Comment: @Vlad274 That might be the way I have to go.  how do I fake a migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database equals to initial migration execute this command:

```
Update-Database -Script -IgnoreChanges -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

After that for every new migration execute:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

This command will check for every migration if it was already applied to database and if it is it wont apply it again. So the generated migration script will work no matter in which state is database.

Comment: is there a programmatic approach to that?  I'm running the migrations at application startup.

Comment: The command with -IgnoreChanges must be executed if an initial migration should not be applied, but after that you could enable automatic migrations by putting this in your code Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext, Configuration>());